# kaggleでoutputフォルダにcsvを出力できない

Tags: python, kaggle

#### 前提・実現したいこと

kaggleのoutputフォルダに出力できないので、出力する方法を教えてほしい

#### 該当のソースコード

```py
df_out[["PassengerId","Survived"]].to_csv("/kaggle/output/submission.csv",index=False)
```

#### 発生している問題・エラーメッセージ

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/kaggle/output/submission.csv'
```

#### 補足情報（FW/ツールのバージョンなど）

データの読み込みはうまくいく。
outputフォルダはinputフォルダ同様、kaggle以下にある。

```py
df = pd.read_csv("/kaggle/input/titanic/train.csv")
```

Comment: 「No such file or directory: '/kaggle/output/submission.csv'」（直訳）：'/kaggle/output/submission.csv'というファイルもしくはディレクトリがありません）
というエラーが出ているのですから、/kaggleから下のディレクトリとファイルを確認してください。

Comment: imputフォルダとoutputフォルダがあります

Answer (score 0, accepted):

おそらく `/kaggle/output` が作成できなかったためにエラーになっていると思われます。`to_csv` はディレクトリは作ってくれません。セッションが変わって `/kaggle/output` が削除されているのではないでしょうか。

出力ファイルのパスを `/kaggle/working/submission.csv` にしてみてください。

https://www.kaggle.com/docs/notebooks#technical-specifications

> At time of writing, each Notebook editing session is provided with the following resources:
>
> - 9 hours execution time
> - 5 Gigabytes of auto-saved disk space (/kaggle/working)
> - Additional scratchpad disk space (outside /kaggle/working) that will not be saved outside of the current session

Comment: ありがとうございます。無事出力できました！